# How can I insert a snippet and then open the resulting link?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to look up a table by creating a url and following that link, with one keyboard shortcut. I've been able to do it with two separate shortcuts, but want to combine into one. Here's what I think is close, from my keybindings.json file:

### Doesn't (yet) work:

```json
  {
    "name": "dictionary-lookup",
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
                      "snippet": "https://path/to/proprietary/search/Details?tblName=$TM_SELECTED_TEXT"
                  }
          },
          {
            "command": "editor.action.openLink"
          },
          {
            "command": "undo" //undo the link snippet so it doesn't stay in the code
          }
        ],
  },
    "when": "queryEditorVisible"
  }
```

### Does work, but requires two keyboard shortcuts:

```json
  {
    "name": "dictionary-lookup",
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
                      "snippet": "https://path/to/proprietary/search/Details?tblName=$TM_SELECTED_TEXT"
                  }
          }
        ],
  },
    "when": "queryEditorVisible"
  },
  {
    "name": "follow-link",
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+d",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "command": "editor.action.openLink",
          },
          {
            "command": "undo" //undo the link snippet so it doesn't stay in the code
          }
        ],
  },
    "when": "queryEditorVisible"
  }
```

I wonder if it has to do with the editor taking a second or so to make the link, and have looked for a pause command to no avail. Any suggestions?

Tried breaking into two shortcuts (works, but inconvenient) and looking for a pause command.

Comment: what is the `queryEditorVisible` when clause?

Comment: yes, the problem seems to be that VS Code takes some time to recognize that a link has been added (probably some sort of debouncing).

Comment: I think you might need to write an extension to solve this particular problem.

Comment: VSC calls the Document Link providers and they take time to process async

Comment: with `multi-command` you can add a wait time between commands

Comment: does `editor.action.openLink` accept `args` with variables